# Java-Reading from txt file using scanner, boolean for next line

Tags: java, text, java.util.scanner

Is there a way for java to be able to tell when a line in the text file ends?

I'm trying to put information from a text file into an int array

`1 2 3 
 4 5 6 
 7 8 9`

If the text file was the above numbers, I would want the code to be able to store 1 2 3 and then be able to tell it to stop because the next numbers are in a new line

I couldn't find any boolean in the scanner oracle doc that could help me with this

The amount of numbers in the first line of the text file can vary so I don't want it to stop after only reading 3 numbers, which is what my code currently has

Comment: int array have 1 line..

Comment: Just read a line at a time and split it?

Comment: How can I a read 1 line at a time if I don't know how many numbers  the line will have?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to read by line then with [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) and [`Scanner.hasNextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--). Of course, if you can use Apache Commons then [`FileUtils.readLines(File, String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) makes it easy to read the file line-by-line. Once you have a line, you can use [`Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) which (per the Javadoc)

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified string.

Something like,

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Scanner strScanner = new Scanner(line);
    // ...
}
```

As [@JonSkeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) pointed out in the comments, you can also split the `line` on white-space like

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] arr = line.split("\\s+");
    // ...
}
```

And as [@RealSkeptic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4125191/realskeptic) points out below might also use [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-). That might give you a full example like

```
// Get the user's home directory
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File f = new File(home, "input.txt");
try {
    // Get all of the lines into a List
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(f.toPath());
    // Get the line count to create an array.
    int[][] arr = new int[lines.size()][];
    // populate the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
        // split each line on white space
        String[] parts = lines.get(i).split("\\s+");
        arr[i] = new int[parts.length];
        for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
            // parse each integer.
            arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(parts[j]);
        }
    }
    // Display the multidimensional array.
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Display any error.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Note that Apache Commons is not needed - one cas use [`Files.readAllLines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can read line-by-line using BufferedReader as follows:

```
public class ReadLine {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    try {
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            line = br.readLine();
            final Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
            while(s.hasNextInt()) {
                final int i = s.nextInt();
                // code using i here
            }
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

}